# jQuery UI Calendar Displaying Events onLoad

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a jQuery UI DatePicker calendar that `alerts` when a date is clicked that has an event.  http://jsfiddle.net/helpinspireme/DuwZL/  What I would like to add is on load, if there is an event on today's date I would like the alert to display when the calendar is loaded.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

```
var events = [ 
{ Title: "Meeting with boss", Date: new Date("04/13/2012") },
{ Title: "Meeting with manager", Date: new Date("04/13/2012") },
{ Title: "Five K for charity", Date: new Date("04/17/2012") }, 
{ Title: "Dinner", Date: new Date("04/25/2012") }
];

$("div").datepicker({
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var result = [true, '', null];
    var matching = $.grep(events, function(event) {
        return event.Date.valueOf() === date.valueOf();
    });

    if (matching.length) {
        result = [true, 'highlight', null];
    }
    return result;
},
onSelect: function(dateText) {
    var date,
        selectedDate = new Date(dateText),
        i = 0,
        event = null;

    while (i < events.length) {
        date = events[i].Date;

        if (selectedDate.valueOf() === date.valueOf()) {
            event = events[i];
            alert(event.Title);
        }
        i++;
    }
}
});
```

​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, add this:

```
$('.ui-datepicker-today').trigger('click');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/DuwZL/4/)**.

Comment: Perfect.  I was way over thinking this solution.  Thanks for your help.